# It was the Homer's car

Tags: articles

Can we use "the" article before names in possession, like:

> It was the Homer's car

or it should be

> It was Homer's car

Comment: Who or what is *Homer*? Is he/she/it/they commonly referred to as *the Homer* in other circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

**<strike>It was the Homer's car</strike>** is incorrect.

You must use

- **It was Homer's car**
- It was **mum's car**

Use an article when it's not a name:

- It was **a teacher's car**
- It was **the doctor's car**

To express indeterminate or determinate:

- If Homer has many cars: It was **one of Homer's cars**
- If having several things is common, to stress it's the only one: It was **Homer's only cup**

The following are fairly rare, but completely ordinary expressions.    Note that many native speakers will make errors on these possessives.

To express ownership by a family, you can use a family name "Smith" as an adjective, or make the name plural to indicate the family ("the Smiths"), and then possessive:

- It was **the Smith car** (family name as adjective)
- It was **the Smiths' car** (possessive of plural "the Smiths")

If the name ends in S is would correctly be any of the following, but native speakers vary and use both "Jones'" or "Jones's".

- It was **the Jones car** (family name Jones as adjective)
- It was **the Jones' car**
- It was **the Jones's car**

**Even more rarely** is where a person is known as "The Something".  There are two cases

1. Where a name is common but there is a particular famous person of that name, you use stressed "a" and "the" to determine if it's the famous person or just someone with the same name.  "Whose car is that?" "John Lennon's"  "Is that *a* John Lennon's car or *the* John Lennon's car?" "**It's *the* John Lennons's car**"
2. Where the individual is routinely known by a nickname such as **The Fonz** (TV character), **The Gipper** (Ronald Reagan), **The Edge** (guitarist) or **The Donald** (Donald Trump).  "**It's The Donald's car**".  These cases are extremely rare; arguably "The Donald" is a functioning as an unusual name, and apparently originates from his first wife, a non-native speaker. [ref](https://observer.com/1999/01/trump-vs-trump-in-battle-of-the-exes/).

Comment: unless it's the possession of a plural ie "It was the Homer's car" being the car belonging to the Homer family.

Comment: thanks @GeeTee, yes but possessive apostrophe comes after: I added this to the answer

Comment: of course it does - my bad - Doh!!

Comment: So, "it was the Homer's car" means personally it was not his car but his family's"?

Comment: No: "It was the Homer's car" is incorrect.  I've clarified the answer a little.  The family examples are quite rare compared to the others.

Comment: As a blanket statement, this is false. For instance, the current US president could easily say *it was the Donald's plane*. Using an article in this way is unusual, but it's not *always* wrong.

Comment: thanks @JasonBassford of course you're right.  I added it to the answer.